# AttributeError: 'mainscreen' object has no attribute 'attributes'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

could you please lead me to a solution, I can't fix this on my own.

I get an AttributeError: 'mainscreen' object has no attribute 'attributes'
when I press the button to toggle to fullscreen.
thx for your help

```
#!/bin/python3

import tkinter
import grovepi
import math
import time
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class mainscreen:
    def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    master.title ("Temperature")
    master.geometry("800x480")
    master.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
    self.state = False

    sensorTH1 = 4
    sensorTH2 = 3
    temp1=0
    temp2=0


    #column0 and 1
    self.labeltemp11 = tkinter.Label (master, text="Temp inside", fg="black", font="72")
    self.labeltemp11.grid(row=1, column=0 ,sticky="sw")
    self.labeltemp1 =tkinter.Label (master, text="", fg="black", font="72")
    self.labeltemp1.grid(row=1, column=1,sticky="sw")
    self.labelhum11 = tkinter.Label(master, text="Hum inside", fg="black",  font="72")
    self.labelhum11.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="sw")
    self.labelhum1 = tkinter.Label (master, text="",fg="black", font="72")
    self.labelhum1.grid(row=2, column=1,sticky="sw")
    self.labeltemp22 = tkinter.Label (master, text="Temp outside", fg="black",font="72")
    self.labeltemp22.grid(row=3, column=0,sticky="sw")
    self.labeltemp2 = tkinter.Label (master, text="", fg="black",  font="72")
    self.labeltemp2.grid(row=3, column=1,sticky="sw")
    self.labelhum22 = tkinter.Label(master, text="Hum outside", fg="black",  font="72")
    self.labelhum22.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="sw")
    self.labelhum2 = tkinter.Label (master, text="", fg="black",  font="72")
    self.labelhum2.grid(row=4, column=1,sticky="sw")
    #win.focus_set()
    #win.bind("t",toggle_fullscreen(win))
    self.button= tkinter.Button(master, text="No fullscreen", width=10,command=lambda:self.toggle_fullscreen())
    #works as well button= tkinter.Button(win, text="No Fullscreen", width=10,command=toggle_fullscreen)
    self.button.grid(column=0,row=5,sticky="nsew")

    #column2 empty
    self.labelemp1 = tkinter.Label (master, text="", fg="black", width="10" ,bg="white" , font="72")
    self.labelemp1.grid(row=0, column=2,sticky="sw")
    self.labelemp2 = tkinter.Label (master, text="test", fg="black", width="10",bg="black" , font="72")
    self.labelemp2.grid(row=0, column=3,sticky="sw")



    def READ(toggle):
        if toggle:
        [temp1,humidity1] = grovepi.dht(sensorTH1,1)
        self.labeltemp1.configure(text= "{value:6.2f} C".format( value=temp1))
        self.labelhum1.configure(text= "{value:6.2f} %".format( value=humidity1))
        print ("temp1 =", temp1, " humidity1 =", humidity1) #py3

    else: 
        #time.sleep(1)
        [temp2,humidity2] = grovepi.dht(sensorTH2,1)
        self.labeltemp2.configure(text= "{value:6.2f} C".format( value=temp2))
        self.labelhum2.configure(text= "{value:6.2f} %".format( value=humidity2))
        print ("temp2 =", temp2, " humidity2 =", humidity2) #py3


        toggle= not toggle
        #print (toggle)
        return(toggle)






    def read_every_second(self):
    #global readoneortwo not needed after object oriented programming
    #win.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
    #toggle_fullscreen(win)
        readoneortwo=self.READ(readoneortwo)
        master.after(1000, read_every_second)

    # can be used with call of button lamda: toggle_fullscreen (win) or any other window?
    #def toggle_fullscreen(self, event=None):
    #        self.state = not self.state  # Just toggling the boolean
    #        print ("test")
    #        self.attributes("-fullscreen", self.state)
    #        return "break"


    def toggle_fullscreen(self, event=None):
        self.state = not self.state  # Just toggling the boolean
        if self.state:
        self.button["text"]="No Fullscreen"
        else:
        self.button["text"]="Fullscreen"
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", master.state)
        return "break"    

if __name__ == '__main__':
root = tkinter.Tk()
win = mainscreen(root)
#win.read_every_second ()
root.mainloop()
```

If I want to run win.read_every_second() I get an Error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'readoneortwo' referenced before assignment

I was told to use object oriented and class so I do not need global variables , but it seems I do ??

Comment: At the top, you set `master.attributes("-fullscreen", False)`, yet at the bottom you use `self`: `self.attributes("-fullscreen", master.state)`.

Comment: Quite Frankly, I do not understand as I am to new ....I thought self.master = master..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue change `toggle_fullscreen` as follows:

```
def toggle_fullscreen(self, event=None):
    self.state = not self.state  # Just toggling the boolean
    if self.state:
        self.button["text"]="No Fullscreen"
    else:
        self.button["text"]="Fullscreen"

    self.master.attributes("-fullscreen", self.state)

    return "break"
```

And notice the change to `self.state` ( from `master.state` ).

You write: `I was told to use object oriented and class so I do not need global variables , but it seems I do??`

> Using class you don't need global variables as long as you use the syntax **`self.someVariable = someValue`**. Every function of the class gets `self` passed as its first parameter making all the `self.someVariable` variables defined within the class available from within the function (as if they were "global").

Comment: Thx Claudio, I think this is the best site for programmers , I came that far :-) with answers found here already by searching...